# Auto play html5 video on mobile browser

Tags: html, video, mobile, safari

It is argued that html5 video cannot be automatically payed in mobile browsers. 
However, I found this website autoplaying video (though not looping it) on mobile:

http://campaign.nissan.co.il/qashqai0515

How is this possible?

Comment: Regardless of whether it can be done or not, it's bad practice and highly annoying and shouldn't be done.

Comment: I agree that it may be annoying, but this is a technology question.. not user experiece

Answer (score 3):

Autoplay does not work on all versions of iOS and modern versions of Android. Both platforms require the user to click the video or a play button to initiate video play. It was made this way to conserve the devices battery life and limit cellular bandwidth.

There have been some workarounds in the past that use javascript to trigger the play event however from my testing those workarounds no longer work. Another trick is showing a sequence of images that looks like a video - Apple has done this in the past.

Note: I tested the link you provided in iOS 8 and it does not autoplay.

Comment: I am surprised it didn't work - I have tried it on iOS 8.1 and it worked perfectly. What 8.x are you running?

Comment: iOS 8.3. Website was viewed in Safari for iOS